# How can I induce these two datasets for a linear regression model in R?

Tags: r

For linear regression y_i=ax_i+epsilon. If I want to let x_i from the dataset `Air.Flow` (represents the rate of operation of the plant) and y_i from `stack.loss`(the dependent variable) in R.

How can I input these two datasets in R?

For example, the code

```
 library(BAS)
 data(bodyfat)
 summary(bodyfat)
```

is to use data set `bodyfat` from the library `BAS`. Is there any library for `Air.Flow` and `stack.loss`?

The linear regression is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the dataset `stackloss` from the library `datasets`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the data first:

```
df = datasets::stackloss
lm(df$Air.Flow ~ df$stack.loss)
```

Comment: When I run this code, there is an error: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Air.flow' not found

Comment: It works now. So there are total of 21 data samples from these two `Air.Flow` and `stack.loss`?

Comment: Yes. If it solved, please accept the answer to mark this post as solved :). Also, may i ask why do you want to work with this dataset?

Comment: Can I get more data for `stack.loss`? 21 samples are a bit small.

Comment: I try to use this dataset to test the linear regression model.

Comment: Well, this dataset seems not a good set for testing linear regression... I plot the figure below this question.

Comment: This has only 21 observations, if you want more you need to find som other dataset. You just want to find a large dataset to run an example of linear regression?